# Positive value of a number

Tags: math

Want to compute `(- dcur dmax)` and if negative, I want it changed to positive.  Is that a function in elisp that gives the positive value of a number?

Comment: `C-h f abs` - as in most languages.

Comment: @NickD Please write an answer to mark the question as answered. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute value function `abs` does this in Elisp, as well as in most programming languages:

```
(abs (- dcur dmax))
```

I would normally suggest `C-h f abs` to read the doc string of the function, but unless you know what `absolute value` means in math, it is not very informative:

```
(abs ARG)

Return the absolute value of ARG.
```